# ios check if nsarray == null

Tags: ios, null, nsarray

I'm receiving some response from `JSON`, and is working fine, but I need to check for some `null` values,

I have found different answers but seems is not working still,

```
NSArray *productIdList = [packItemDictionary objectForKey:@"ProductIdList"];
```

I have tried with

```
if ( !productIdList.count )  //which breaks the app,

if ( productIdList == [NSNull null] )  // warning: comparison of distinct pointer types (NSArray and NSNull)
```

So what is happening? How to fix this and check for `null` in my array?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean “brakes the app”?  If it's raising an exception, post the log messages.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Eliminate the warning using a cast:

```
if (productIdList == (id)[NSNull null])
```

If `productIdList` is in fact `[NSNull null]`, then doing `productIdList.count` will raise an exception because `NSNull` does not understand the `count` message.

Comment: @MaKo ... and, implicitly, this works because `[NSNull null]` always returns the same object. `==` compares identity, not value.

Comment: I missed the cast to 'id' & was missing this check (ignored it due to compiler warning) for long time! thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can also check class of an object by using method `isKindOfClass:`.

For example, in your case you could do following:

```
if ([productIdList isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
{
     // value is valid
}
```

or (if you are sure that `NSNull` is indicating invalid value)

```
if([productIdList isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
{
     // value is invalid
}
```

Comment: There is only one singleton instance of `NSNull` so using `==` to check for it is shorter and more efficient.

Comment: But checking type of returned object is more safely.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `isEqual` selector:

```
if ( [productIdList isEqual:[NSNull null]] )
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be clear what you want to check:
the array is null which means the variable doesn't exist:

```
array == nil
```

Or the array has zero element which you can :

```
[array count] == 0
```

Comment: The `NSDictionary` class cannot store `nil` as a value, so JSON parsers (and property list parsers) use `[NSNull null]` instead to represent a null value, because there is a difference between a key being present with a null value, and a key being absent.

Comment: The first line says all.